# I swear this worked yesterday!! - mysterious compiler error

Tags: arduino-mega, compile, debugging, debug, compiler

I thought I finally had this working yesterday, the code compiled, and executed on the arduino, there were however some small quirks but today I went to fix a small timing issue, but got the following errors instead.  Nothing related to the errors was changed, they just showed up, in fact I went back to the original code which was compiling fine yesterday and it won't compile either.  The errors are directly below this followed by the libraries which appear to be the cause of the errors.  Please help, I just want to get this project finished.

```
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Mac OS X), TD: 1.28-beta1, Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

In file included from /Users/DMYoung1/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.13/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:28:0,
from /Users/DMYoung1/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Morse_EnDecoder/MorseEnDecoder.h:7,
from /Users/DMYoung1/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Morse_EnDecoder/MorseEnDecoder.cpp:67:
/Users/DMYoung1/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Morse_EnDecoder/MorseEnDecoder.cpp:75:19: error: variable 'morseTable' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
char morseTable[] PROGMEM = 
               ^
exit status 1
Error compiling for "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560"
```

I am attaching my code and the libraries I am using.

Morse EnDecoder.h

```
#ifndef MorseEnDecoder_H
#define MorseEnDecoder_H

#if (ARDUINO <  100)
#include <WProgram.h>
#else
#include <Arduino.h> 
#endif

#define MORSE_AUDIO true
#define MORSE_KEYER false
#define MORSE_ACTIVE_LOW true
#define MORSE_ACTIVE_HIGH false


class morseDecoder
{
public:
morseDecoder(int decodePin, boolean listenAudio, boolean morsePullup);
void decode();
void setspeed(int value);
char read();
boolean available();
int AudioThreshold;
long debounceDelay;     // the debounce time. Keep well below dotTime!!
boolean morseSignalState;  
private:
int morseInPin;         // The Morse input pin
int audioSignal;
int morseTablePointer;
int wpm;                // Word-per-minute speed
long dotTime;           // morse dot time length in ms
long dashTime;
long wordSpace;
boolean morseSpace;     // Flag to prevent multiple received spaces
boolean gotLastSig;     // Flag that the last received morse signal is decoded as dot or dash
boolean morseKeyer;
boolean lastKeyerState;
boolean morseAudio;
boolean activeLow;
long markTime;          // timers for mark and space in morse signal
long spaceTime;         // E=MC^2 ;p
long lastDebounceTime;  // the last time the input pin was toggled
long currentTime;       // The current (signed) time
char decodedMorseChar;  // The last decoded Morse character
};




class morseEncoder
{
public:
morseEncoder(int encodePin);
void encode();
void setspeed(int value);
void write(char temp);
boolean available();
int morseSignals;       // nr of morse signals to send in one morse character
char morseSignalString[7];// Morse signal for one character as temporary ASCII string of dots and dashes
private:
char encodeMorseChar;   // ASCII character to encode
boolean sendingMorse;
int wpm;                // Word-per-minute speed
long dotTime;           // morse dot time length in ms
long dashTime;
long wordSpace;
int morseSignalPos;
int sendingMorseSignalNr;
long sendMorseTimer;
long lastDebounceTime;
long currentTime;
protected:
int morseOutPin;
virtual void setup_signal();
virtual void start_signal(bool startOfChar, char signalType);
virtual void stop_signal(bool endOfChar, char signalType);
};


#endif
```

Here is Morse EnDecoder.cpp

```
/*          MORSE ENDECODER

- Morse encoder / decoder classes for the Arduino.

Copyright (C) 2010-2012 raron

GNU GPLv3 license:

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Details: http://raronoff.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/morse-endecoder/

#include "MorseEnDecoder.h"


// Morse code binary tree table (dichotomic search table)

// ITU with most punctuation (but without non-english characters - for now)
const int morseTreeLevels = 6; // Minus top level, also the max nr. of morse signals
const int morseTableLength = pow(2,morseTreeLevels+1);
const char morseTable[] PROGMEM =
" ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF*L*PJBXCYZQ!*54*3***2&*+****16=/***(*7***8*90*"
"***********?_****\"**.****@***'**-********;!*)*****,****:*******\0";

morseDecoder::morseDecoder(int decodePin, boolean listenAudio, boolean morsePullup)
{
morseInPin = decodePin;
morseAudio = listenAudio;
activeLow = morsePullup;

if (morseAudio == false)
{
pinMode(morseInPin, INPUT);
if (activeLow) digitalWrite (morseInPin, HIGH);
}

// Some initial values  
wpm = 13;
AudioThreshold = 700;
debounceDelay = 20;
dotTime = 1200 / wpm;       // morse dot time length in ms
dashTime = 3 * 1200 / wpm;
wordSpace = 7 * 1200 / wpm;

morseTablePointer = 0;

morseKeyer = LOW;
morseSignalState = LOW;
lastKeyerState = LOW;

gotLastSig = true;
morseSpace = true;
decodedMorseChar = '\0';

lastDebounceTime = 0;
markTime = 0;
spaceTime = 0;
}



void morseDecoder::setspeed(int value)
{
wpm = value;
if (wpm <= 0) wpm = 1;
dotTime = 1200 / wpm;
dashTime = 3 * 1200 / wpm;
wordSpace = 7 * 1200 / wpm;
}

boolean morseDecoder::available()
{
if (decodedMorseChar) return true; else return false;
}

char morseDecoder::read()
{
char temp = decodedMorseChar;
decodedMorseChar = '\0';
return temp;
}

void morseDecoder::decode()
{
currentTime = millis();

// Read Morse signals
if (morseAudio == false)
{
// Read the Morse keyer (digital)
morseKeyer = digitalRead(morseInPin);
if (activeLow) morseKeyer = !morseKeyer;

// If the switch changed, due to noise or pressing:
if (morseKeyer != lastKeyerState) lastDebounceTime = currentTime; // reset timer

// debounce the morse keyer
if ((currentTime - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay)
{
  // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer
  // than the debounce delay, so take it as the actual current state:
  morseSignalState = morseKeyer;

  // differentiante mark and space times
  if (morseSignalState) markTime = lastDebounceTime; 
  else spaceTime = lastDebounceTime;
}
} else {
// Read Morse audio signal
audioSignal = analogRead(morseInPin);
if (audioSignal > AudioThreshold)
{
  // If this is a new morse signal, reset morse signal timer
  if (currentTime - lastDebounceTime > dotTime/2)
  {
    markTime = currentTime;
    morseSignalState = true; // there is currently a Morse signal
  }
  lastDebounceTime = currentTime;
} else {
  // if this is a new pause, reset space time
  if (currentTime - lastDebounceTime > dotTime/2 && morseSignalState == true)
  {
    spaceTime = lastDebounceTime; // not too far off from last received audio
    morseSignalState = false;     // No more signal
   }
 }
}



// Decode morse code
if (!morseSignalState)
{
  if (!gotLastSig)
  {
    if (morseTablePointer < morseTableLength/2-1)
    {
    // if pause for more than half a dot, get what kind of signal pulse (dot/dash) received last
    if (currentTime - spaceTime > dotTime/2)
    {
      // if signal for more than 1/4 dotTime, take it as a morse pulse
      if (spaceTime-markTime > dotTime/4)
      {
        morseTablePointer *= 2;  // go one level down the tree
        // if signal for less than half a dash, take it as a dot
        if (spaceTime-markTime < dashTime/2)
        {
           morseTablePointer++; // point to node for a dot
           gotLastSig = true;
        }
        // else if signal for between half a dash and a dash + one dot (1.33 dashes), take as a dash
        else if (spaceTime-markTime < dashTime + dotTime)
        {
           morseTablePointer += 2; // point to node for a dash
           gotLastSig = true;
        }
      }
    }
  } else { // error if too many pulses in one morse character
    //Serial.println("<ERROR: unrecognized signal!>");
    decodedMorseChar = '#'; // error mark
    gotLastSig = true;
    morseTablePointer = 0;
  }
}
// Write out the character if pause is longer than 2/3 dash time (2 dots) and a character received
if ((currentTime-spaceTime >= (dotTime*2)) && (morseTablePointer > 0))
{
  decodedMorseChar = pgm_read_byte_near(morseTable + morseTablePointer);
  morseTablePointer = 0;
}
// Write a space if pause is longer than 2/3rd wordspace
if (currentTime-spaceTime > (wordSpace*2/3) && morseSpace == false)
{
  decodedMorseChar = ' ';
  morseSpace = true ; // space written-flag
}

} else {
// while there is a signal, reset some flags
gotLastSig = false;
morseSpace = false;
}

// Save the morse keyer state for next round
lastKeyerState = morseKeyer;
}

morseEncoder::morseEncoder(int encodePin)
{
  morseOutPin = encodePin;
  this->setup_signal();

// some initial values
sendingMorse = false;
encodeMorseChar = '\0';

wpm = 13;
dotTime = 1200 / wpm;       // morse dot time length in ms
dashTime = 3 * 1200 / wpm;
wordSpace = 7 * 1200 / wpm;

}

void morseEncoder::setspeed(int value)
{
wpm = value;
if (wpm <= 0) wpm = 1;
dotTime = 1200 / wpm;
dashTime = 3 * 1200 / wpm;
wordSpace = 7 * 1200 / wpm;
}

boolean morseEncoder::available()
{
if (sendingMorse) return false; else return true;
}

void morseEncoder::write(char temp)
{
if (!sendingMorse && temp != '*') encodeMorseChar = temp;
}

void morseEncoder::setup_signal()
{
pinMode(morseOutPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(morseOutPin, LOW);
}

void morseEncoder::start_signal(bool startOfChar, char signalType)
{
digitalWrite(morseOutPin, HIGH);
}

void morseEncoder::stop_signal(bool endOfChar, char signalType)
{
digitalWrite(morseOutPin, LOW);
}

void morseEncoder::encode()
{
currentTime = millis();

if (!sendingMorse && encodeMorseChar)
{
// change to capital letter if not
if (encodeMorseChar > 96) encodeMorseChar -= 32;

// Scan for the character to send in the Morse table
int p;
for (p=0; p<morseTableLength+1; p++) if (pgm_read_byte_near(morseTable + p) == encodeMorseChar) break;

if (p >= morseTableLength) p = 0; // not found, but send a space instead


// Reverse binary tree path tracing
int pNode; // parent node
morseSignals = 0;

// Travel the reverse path from position p to the top of the morse table
if (p > 0)
{
  // build the morse signal (backwards morse signal string from last signal to first)
  pNode = p;
  while (pNode > 0)
  {
    if ( (pNode & 0x0001) == 1)
    {
      // It is a dot
      morseSignalString[morseSignals++] = '.';
    } else {
      // It is a dash
      morseSignalString[morseSignals++] = '-';
    }
    // Find parent node
    pNode = int((pNode-1)/2);
  }
} else { // Top of Morse tree - Add the top space character
  // cheating a little; a wordspace for a "morse signal"
  morseSignalString[morseSignals++] = ' ';
}

morseSignalString[morseSignals] = '\0';


// start sending the the character
sendingMorse = true;
sendingMorseSignalNr = morseSignals; // Sending signal string backwards
sendMorseTimer = currentTime;
if (morseSignalString[0] != ' ') this->start_signal(true, morseSignalString[morseSignals-1]);
}


// Send Morse signals to output
if (sendingMorse)
{
char& currSignalType = morseSignalString[sendingMorseSignalNr-1];
bool endOfChar = sendingMorseSignalNr <= 1;
switch (currSignalType)
{
  case '.': // Send a dot (actually, stop sending a signal after a "dot time")
    if (currentTime - sendMorseTimer >= dotTime)
    {
      this->stop_signal(endOfChar, currSignalType);
      sendMorseTimer = currentTime;
      currSignalType = 'x'; // Mark the signal as sent
    }
    break;
  case '-': // Send a dash (same here, stop sending after a dash worth of time)
    if (currentTime - sendMorseTimer >= dashTime)
    {
      this->stop_signal(endOfChar, currSignalType);
      sendMorseTimer = currentTime;
      currSignalType = 'x'; // Mark the signal as sent
    }
    break;
  case 'x': // To make sure there is a pause between signals
    if (sendingMorseSignalNr > 1)
    {
      // Pause between signals in the same letter
      if (currentTime - sendMorseTimer >= dotTime)
      {
        sendingMorseSignalNr--;
        this->start_signal(false, morseSignalString[sendingMorseSignalNr-1]); // Start sending the next signal
        sendMorseTimer = currentTime;       // reset the timer
      }
    } else {
      // Pause between letters
      if (currentTime - sendMorseTimer >= dashTime)
      {
        sendingMorseSignalNr--;
        sendMorseTimer = currentTime;       // reset the timer
      }
    }
    break;
  case ' ': // Pause between words (minus pause between letters - already sent)
  default:  // Just in case its something else
    if (currentTime - sendMorseTimer > wordSpace - dashTime) sendingMorseSignalNr--;
}
if (sendingMorseSignalNr <= 0 )
{
  // Ready to encode more letters
  sendingMorse = false;
  encodeMorseChar = '\0';
}
}
}
```

And finally, here is my code!!

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <MorseEnDecoder.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <morse.h>
#define PIN_STATUS  13
#define CPU_RESTART_ADDR (uint32_t *)0xE000ED0C
#define CPU_RESTART_VAL 0x5FA0004
#define CPU_RESTART (*CPU_RESTART_ADDR = CPU_RESTART_VAL);

// Pin mapping
const byte morseInPin = 7;      
const byte morseOutPin = 13;
String check = "";
String origin = "SOS";
const int maxItems = 3;
int x;
char myArray[maxItems], curChar;
char nextChar;
int i;
int y;

// Instantiate Morse objects
morseDecoder morseInput(morseInPin, MORSE_KEYER, MORSE_ACTIVE_LOW);
morseEncoder morseOutput(morseOutPin);

// Variables dealing with formatting the output somewhat
// by inserting CR's (carriage returns)
long lastTransmissionTime;
long currentTime;
boolean transmissionEnded = true; // Flag to mark old transmission is finished

// Minimum transmission pause time to insert carriage returns (CR)
// Adjust depending on Morse speed. IE 13 wpm = 646 ms between words (no CR).
const long transmissionPaused   = 1000; // Suitable for 13 wpm?

LEDMorseSender sender(PIN_STATUS);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Morse EnDecoder Geocache");

// Setting Morse speed in wpm - words per minute
// If not set, 13 wpm is default anyway
morseInput.setspeed(5);
morseOutput.setspeed(5);

lastTransmissionTime = (long)millis();

}

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; //declare reset function @ address 0

void loop()
{
currentTime = (long)millis();

// Need to call these once per loop
morseInput.decode();
morseOutput.encode();

// RECEIVE MORSE (INPUT)
// If a character is decoded from the input, write it to serial port
if (morseInput.available())
{

char receivedMorse = morseInput.read();
Serial.print(receivedMorse);
// A little error checking    
if (receivedMorse == '#') Serial.println("< ERROR:too many morse signals! >");
morseOutput.write('#');
morseOutput.encode();

//Create Array out of receivedMorse Chars

    curChar = 0;
    nextChar = receivedMorse;
    curChar +=nextChar;
    myArray[i] = curChar;
    check.concat(myArray[i]);
    Serial.println(check);

//Check input and respond
if (check == origin)      //GOOD JOB!!  Your reward is as follows
{
Serial.println("check = origin");
Serial.println(check);
sender.setup();
sender.setWPM(5);
sender.setMessage(String("help is coming"));
sender.startSending();
}
else if (check =="S") {}                   
else if (check == "SO") {}
else if (check == " SOS") {}
else if (check.length() >4)
{
delay(100);
Serial.println("resetting");
delay(500);
resetFunc();  //call reset 
delay(100);
}
else {}                                     
}
sender.continueSending();
}
```

Comment: Did you update the Arduino IDE or AVR GCC toolchain? That would explain the compiler error. More recent versions of the compiler will require program memory data structures to be declared "const".

Comment: I don't believe that I did, do you happen to know a version number that I could try to revert to?

Comment: I went back to 1.6.10, that didn't fix the error, it does not appear that the ide was updated since this has happened.  I am also using IDE 1.6.7 which has been out since december and I have not updated it recently.  I am however updating to 1.6.11 to see if that will fix it and if not, plan to return to 1.6.7 as I have had trouble with the new software in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have made multiple copies of MorseEnDecoder.cpp, some of them modified, because the `morseTable[]` declaration shown in the error message is different than that shown in the code you said is MorseEnDecoder.cpp.  Specifically, line 32 of that code is

```
const char morseTable[] PROGMEM =
```

while the error message refers to a line 75 which reads

```
char morseTable[] PROGMEM =
```

The solution is to extirpate extraneous copies and restore MorseEnDecoder.cpp to a correct version.

Comment: I dowloaded the original code, before I posted this question, to attempt to confirm that this was not the case.  The original code and library would not compile either.  I will look at this again though.

Comment: I have downloaded everything again, and replaced my old files.  This did not fix the error.

Comment: Search your file system for files named MorseEnDecoder.cpp and see if one of them has the line without `const` at front.  Eg, on a linux system, `grep 'char morseTable' $(locate MorseEnDecoder.cpp)`

Comment: WOW!!  Well, that fixed it.  I would likely have never found that!!